# Проблема с отображением фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Имеется следующий код, главное активити и два фрагмента. код ошибок не выдает но фрагменты не отображаются!

з.ы.  там где закомментированы строки с адаптером - тоже проблема, выдает NullPointerExeption

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("List"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("CheckBox"));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagesAdapter adapter = new PagesAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

ListFragment.java

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mInputSearch;

private ArrayList<String> mList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    fillArray();

//        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    ((getActivity().getParent()).getApplicationContext(),
 //                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mInputSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

 //        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return v; }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



    mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListFragment.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

private void fillArray() {

    mList.add("Lorem");
    mList.add("Ipsum");
    mList.add("Dolor");
    mList.add("Sit");
    mList.add("Amet");
    mList.add("Consectetur");
    mList.add("Adipiscing");
    mList.add("Elit");
    mList.add("Fusce");
    mList.add("Pharetra");
    mList.add("Luctus");
    mList.add("Sodales");

    Collections.sort(mList);
}
}
```

CheckBoxFragment.java

```
public class CheckBoxFragment extends Fragment {

private CheckBox mCheckBox13, mCheckBox42, mCheckBox121;
private TextView mTextViewForFont, mTextViewSum;

private int mSumCounter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_checkbox, container, false);
    mCheckBox13 = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox13);
    mCheckBox42 = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox42);
    mCheckBox121 = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox121);

    mTextViewForFont = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewForFont);
    mTextViewSum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSum);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/verdanab.ttf");
    mTextViewForFont.setTypeface(face);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mCheckBox13.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                mSumCounter += 13;
                mTextViewSum.setText("Sum = " + String.valueOf(mSumCounter));
            }else {
                mSumCounter-=13;
                mTextViewSum.setText("Sum = " + String.valueOf(mSumCounter));
            }
        }
    });

    mCheckBox42.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                mSumCounter += 42;
                mTextViewSum.setText("Sum = " + String.valueOf(mSumCounter));
            }else {
                mSumCounter -= 42;
                mTextViewSum.setText("Sum = " + String.valueOf(mSumCounter));
            }
        }
    });

    mCheckBox121.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                mSumCounter += 121;
                mTextViewSum.setText("Sum = " + String.valueOf(mSumCounter));
            } else {
                mSumCounter -= 121;
                mTextViewSum.setText("Sum = " + String.valueOf(mSumCounter));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ListFragment tab1 = new ListFragment();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            CheckBoxFragment tab2 = new CheckBoxFragment();
            return tab2;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">   

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

checkbox_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/textViewForFont"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="13"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Sum = 0"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSum"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="121"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox121"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="42"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox42"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Код разметки покажите.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в адаптере `ViewPager`-а. Приведите его код.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код PagerAdapter.java

Comment: Возможно, вы не видите добавленные фрагменты, т.к. в их разметке почти пусто? Попробуйте добавить непрозрачный фон корневым элементам их разметки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нашел ошибку, действительно, проблема была в разметке главной активити. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> з.ы. там где закомментированы строки с адаптером - тоже проблема,
>   выдает NullPointerExeption

У вас там `getActivity().getParent()`.

`getParent()` возвращает родительскую `Activity`, если эта въюха встроена. У вас там используется [ActivityGroup](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)? Если `Activity` - корень иерархии, то `getParent()` и должен `null` возвращать.

Comment: заменил  getActivity().getParent() на  getActivity()   и ошибка, пропала. Т.е.  если корень иерархии Activity  то нужно использовать getActivity(),  а если используется  ActivityGroup, то getActivity().getParent() ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov в вашем случае вроде как можно использовать `getActivity()` всегда, независимо от того, используется ли ` ActivityGroup`, так как вам нужен только контекст.